# Problema con cuestionario HTML, PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy con una aplicación web que ofrece distintas funcionalidades siendo una de ellas la posibilidad de que un usuario cree cuestionarios que otros contesten. El usuario escribe las preguntas con las posibles opciones(máximo 5) y las envía a la base de dato para que aquellos que deseen responderlas puedan acceder a ellas a través de otra página donde se cargan accediendo a la base de datos.
La cuestión es la siguiente:

Las preguntas no necesariamente tienen que ser las mismas para todos los cuestionarios y las respuestas no son múltiples. 
Este es mi código para mostrar las opciones:

```html
//Consulta para conectarse a la base de datos
//Consulta para acceder a la tabla correspondiente

while($fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){

//Se muestra la pregunta

//Código para mostrar las opciones

echo"<td>";?><input type="checkbox" name="opciones" class="other" value="<?php echo $row['id_respuesta'];?> required /><?php echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";echo $fila['opcion'] ;echo "</td>";
echo"<tr>";

}
```

El problema es el siguiente:

He intentado usar radio Button pero la cuestión es que, al emplear el mismo identificador y seleccionar una opción se eliminaban las selecciones de las preguntas anteriores, motivo por el cual he optado por checkbox, solo que el usuario únicamente puede seleccionar una opción de cada pregunta y no varias a la vez como permite checkbox. Mi otra opción es utilizar select en caso de que no sea posible hacerlo con checkbox. ¿Habría alguna manera de conseguirlo con checkbox o radio button?.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes crear un contador para cada pregunta y así podrás concatenar el numero de la pregunta al identificador del radio button.

```
$contador=0;

while($fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){

//Se muestra la pregunta
//Cuando se muestre la pregunta debes aumentar el contador
$contador++;

//Código para mostrar las opciones

//Cuando muestres las opciones concatenas el name con el $contador
echo"<td>";?><input type="radio" name="opciones<?php echo $contador ?>" 
class="other" value="<?php echo 
$row['id_respuesta'];?> required /><?php echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";echo $fila['opcion'] ;echo "</td>";
echo"<tr>";

}
```

Comment: Perfecto. Ya lo entiendo. Ha funcionado. Muchas gracias